# Pseudocode example of quicksort using concurrency

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, quicksort, pseudocode

I am a first year CS student at a University. My current assignment is about concurrency and the quicksort algorithm. As this is an assignment, I obviously wish to write the code myself to better understand how everything works. I therefore ask you to use **pseudocode**, and not java, when answering.

My program is supposed to start up at command line with three arguments; an in-file containing words, and out-filename, as well as a number (which will tell the program how many threads to use when sorting the in-file). When I start up the program, it is supposed to sort the words in the in-file using the quicksort algorithm and concurrency. Each thread is assigned a section (with a length of threads divided by number of words) of the array of words from the in-file. When every thread has finished sorting its section of the array, the program will append each array returned by the threads into one long, sorted array of words, and write them to the out-file.

My question is: where should I start? And at what point do I choose a pivot element in the array sections? Once I create the sections, or once the thread working on the section starts? Could you please give me a **pseudocode** example of the quicksort algorithm using threads?

Whew, that's a lot of questions! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: if the starting array is `7,8,1,2,5,6,2,3` and you split the array in half and sort each one, you will get `1,2,7,8` and `2,3,5,6`. How are you supposed to append these two... unless you plan to merge them, but that is Mergesort, not Quicksort

Comment: See also [*Quicksort: Parallelization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Parallelization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Wikipedia Quicksort Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (pseudocode)

```
  function quicksort('array')
      if length('array') ≤ 1
          return 'array'  // an array of zero or one elements is already sorted
      select and remove a pivot value 'pivot' from 'array'
      create empty lists 'less' and 'greater'
-----------Partition section----------
      for each 'x' in 'array'
          if 'x' ≤ 'pivot' then append 'x' to 'less'
          else append 'x' to 'greater'
-----------End Partition section------
      return concatenate(quicksort('less'), 'pivot', quicksort('greater')) // two recursive calls
```

The Partition section **cannot be done concurrently**. However, you can execute the recursive calls with multiple threads, i.e.

```
return concatenate(quicksort('less'), 'pivot', quicksort('greater'))
```

Becomes

```
return concatenate(new Thread(quicksort('less')), 'pivot', new Thread(quicksort('greater')))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is on german:

```
funktion quicksort(links, rechts)
     falls links < rechts dann
         teiler := teile(links, rechts)
         quicksort(links, teiler-1)
         quicksort(teiler+1, rechts)
     ende
 ende

funktion teile(links, rechts)
 i := links 
 // Starte mit j links vom Pivotelement
 j := rechts - 1
 pivot := daten[rechts]

 wiederhole

     // Suche von links ein Element, welches größer als das Pivotelement ist
     wiederhole solange daten[i] ≤ pivot und i < rechts
         i := i + 1
     ende

     // Suche von rechts ein Element, welches kleiner als das Pivotelement ist
     wiederhole solange daten[j] ≥ pivot und j > links
          j := j - 1 
     ende

     falls i < j dann
         tausche daten[i] mit daten[j]
     ende

 solange i < j // solange i an j nicht vorbeigelaufen ist 

 // Tausche Pivotelement (daten[rechts]) mit neuer endgültiger Position (daten[i])

 falls daten[i] > pivot dann
         tausche daten[i] mit daten[rechts]
 ende

 // gib die Position des Pivotelements zurück

 antworte i
 ende
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create multiple thread to quicksort equal portions of the data.  Once each thread is done you can merge sort the results to produce a sorted file.

The main challenge you will have is that reading and writing the file can take so long that using multiple threads is not significantly faster.

---

Another approach is to use a pivot point to break the collection into two parts (possibly uneven) and have two threads sort each side. Repeat this until you have as many threads as cpus and then sort each portion single threaded.  Again you have to be careful that this is more efficient than just use one thread.

Comment: I think this is for a class, his instructor is trying to get him to learn how to write a concurrent program, not write the fastest sorting possible

Comment: @durron597 I suspect you are right, but I take exception to developers who write complex concurrent code without check it actually made it faster.  They are basically wasting their time and those in their team by producing code which is harder to maintain. The first lesson about concurrency is to; only do it when you know you are going to be faster (and it is needed which justifies the extra complexity)